# Generate unique product id

Tags: javascript, html, uuid

I have a page that I receive donations with on my site. My bank's API requires that I generate a unique order id for each transaction. How can i implement this in my code using javascript?

The code I'm using is shown below.

```
Please enter the amount you wish to donate and click on the pay button. Thank you

<form id="&quot;form1”">
  <div>

  Amount:<input id="txtAmt" type="text" />

  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cipg.diamondbank.com/cipg/MerchantServices/UPaybutton.ashx?mercId=xxxxx&amp;CurrencyCode=566" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  upay_settings.setAmountField('txtAmt');
  upay_settings.setOrderId('31-Augdd-2014'); // This is the id I'd want to randomize
  upay_settings.setProduct('Donation');
  upay_settings.setEmail('xxx@xxx.org');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
```